# Insert row with Ajax and then can't see new row with straight PHP in same page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

From a body onload event I get AJAX to insert a row into a database with PHP and then get PHP to read the row count number. Then only PHP is used to get a row count. The counts are shown by using DOM into 2  elements onto the page. The Ajax count is always 1 higher than the straight PHP count. What am I missing here?

The include('connect.inc.php') line returns a new mysqli connection into a $con variable.

index.php - Uses body onload event to start insertEvent function.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Query Test</title>
</head>

<body onload='insertEvent()'>
<a id='ajaxphp'; >AJAX + PHP Row Count:</a><br>
<a id='straightphp'; >Straight PHP Row Count:</a>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function insertEvent()
{
    $.ajax({
          url: 'insertEvent.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {'x': '1', 'y': '1'},
          success: function(data) {
          document.getElementById("ajaxphp").innerHTML= "AJAX + PHP Row Count: " + data;
          }
    });


var numrows = 0;

<?php
include('connect.inc.php');
$con = ConnectToDatabase();

$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER by id ASC";

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query))
    {
        // execute query 
        $stmt->execute();

        //Transfers a result set from the last query
        $stmt->store_result();

        // number of results returned
        $num_rows = ($stmt->num_rows);

        echo "numrows = $num_rows;";

    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>

document.getElementById('straightphp').innerHTML = "Straight PHP Row Count: " + numrows;

}

</script>
```

insertEvent.php - PHP for AJAX call

```
<?php
include('connect.inc.php');
$con = ConnectToDatabase();

$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];

$query = "INSERT INTO events (x, y) VALUES (?,?)";

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) 
{
    // bind parameters for markers 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $x, $y);

    // execute query 
    $stmt->execute();

    //Transfers a result set from the last query
    $stmt->store_result();

}

$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER by id ASC";

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query))
    {
        // execute query 
        $stmt->execute();

        //Transfers a result set from the last query
        $stmt->store_result();

        // number of results returned
        $num_rows = ($stmt->num_rows);

    }

mysqli_close($con);

echo $num_rows;

?>
```

Comment: Because php executes first and after that javascript.

Comment: So... First you count the items in the collection, then you add one, then you count them again, and you're wondering why the second count is one more than the first count?  What am *I* missing here?

Comment: ah yes that makes total sense now. Thanks guys.